# How to copy a picture from another worksheet and paste inside a cell comment

Tags: excel, vba

So I came around the net to find answers for this but found none, what I want my code to do is open a worksheet from a folder get the photo from that worksheet and finally paste to a comment inside a cell in my current workbook. here's my code

```
Dim folder As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    folder = ThisWorkbook.path

End Sub

Sub populatePDA()

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Variant
    Dim path As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim p As Picture
    Dim img As Variant
    Dim cb As Comment

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDA")
    path = folder & "\PDA\"
    fileCount = 0
    fileName = Dir(path & "*.xlsm")

    Do While fileName <> ""

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & fileName) 'Open Workbook
        ws.Range("A3:F3").Insert (xlShiftDown)
        ws.Range("A3") = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B16").Value 'Item Name
        ws.Range("B3") = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B17").Value 'S/N
        ws.Range("C3") = wb.Sheets(1).Range("G7").Value 'Description
        ws.Range("D3") = wb.Sheets(1).Range("H12").Value 'Calibration
        ws.Range("E3") = wb.Sheets(1).Range("H13").Value 'Expiration

        For Each p In wb.Sheets(1).Pictures

            p.CopyPicture
            Set img = ws.Paste
            Set cb = ws.Range("F3").AddComment
            cb.Text Text:=""
            cb.Shape.Fill.UserPicture (img)

        Next p

        wb.Close
        fileName = Dir

    Loop

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have You tried to record macro?

Comment: I couldn't paste a picture inside a comment box manually so recording macro didn't do me any good

Comment: What's going wrong? If we know what line the error is occuring on, then it will be easier to help.
Also worth noting that if you can't manually do something in Excel, then you can rarely achieve it in VBA either, so it's possible that there literally is no way to paste an image in a comment box.

Comment: I was about to accept that fact. can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: [This might help](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/insert-a-picture-into-a-comment-in-excel)

Comment: [Or this](https://www.contextures.com/xlcomments02.html#Picture)

Comment: Are you sure that all the pictures must be inserted in the "F3" range comment? If not, do you have a logic to distribute them between above enumerated cells (Item name, S/N, Description etc.)? I  have some free minutes and I would help with a solution able exactly to do what you try to describe. But before starting it, I would like to exactly understand what you really need. Otherwise, you can use the pieces of code from the existing answer... If, for instance, you name the pictures as the enumerated comments, it is possible to match a picture with a cell. In such a case I need a names array.

Comment: The order of pictures insertion can be also used, if you take care to insert them in a specific order and explain to which range to be distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say anything and I finished something...

I modified a little your code making it to add a new insertion in the working sheet, for a new open file, and process them as (I understood) you need. Please, test the next code:

```
Sub populatePDA()
 Dim fileName As String, path As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, p As Shape, fileCount As Long
 Dim cb As Comment, i As Long, arrCol As Variant, k As Long
  arrCol = Split("A,B,C,D,E", ",")
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDA")
  path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\PDA\"
  fileCount = 0
  fileName = Dir(path & "*.xlsm")

 k = 2
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Do While fileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & fileName) 'Open Workbook
    k = k + 1
        ws.Range("A" & k & ":E" & k).Insert (xlShiftDown)
        ws.Range("A" & k) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B16").Value 'Item Name
        ws.Range("B" & k) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B17").Value 'S/N
        ws.Range("C" & k) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("G7").Value 'Description
        ws.Range("D" & k) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("H12").Value 'Calibration
        ws.Range("E" & k) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("H13").Value 'Expiration
    i = 2
    For Each p In wb.Sheets(1).Shapes
       If p.Type = msoPicture Then
          i = i + 1
          ws.Activate
          If Not ws.Range(arrCol(i - 3) & k).Comment Is Nothing Then _
                                  ws.Range(arrCol(i - 3) & k).Comment.Delete
          Set cb = ws.Range(arrCol(i - 3) & k).AddComment
           cb.text text:=""
           With cb.Shape
              .width = p.width: .height = p.height
           End With
          cb.Shape.Fill.UserPicture (SelImPathCh(p, wb))
       End If
    Next p
    ws.Activate
    wb.Close False

    fileName = Dir
 Loop
 ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

The function able to make the picture insertion is the next (it is called by the main above code):

```
Private Function SelImPathCh(img As Shape, Optional wb As Workbook) As String
  Dim ch As ChartObject, sh As Worksheet, sFile As String
  If Not wb Is Nothing Then Set sh = wb.Sheets(1)
  sFile = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Pict1.jpg"
  Set ch = sh.ChartObjects.Add(left:=1, _
       top:=1, width:=img.width, _
                         height:=img.height)
   If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Activate: sh.Activate
   img.Copy: ch.Activate: ActiveChart.Paste
   ch.Chart.Export sFile
   ch.Delete
   SelImPathCh = sFile
End Function
```

The `wb` variable is `Optional` only for my testing need. I used a sheet of the existing working workbook and I skipped it when called the function...

Comment: `ws.Range("A3:F3").Insert (xlShiftDown)` already works properly for me, I'm more concerned with `cb.Shape.Fill.UserPicture ()` I just really want to know how I could get the photo out of each file inside each file in `ThisWorkbook.path & "\PDA\"` and insert it to a comment inside `Range("F3")` then shift the whole row down to insert another photo from the next file

Comment: SOLVED: I didn't used the function you made tho, but I used the approach you did,

made a temporary chart and then paste the image then export then delete. Thanks man!

Comment: @Thamus: But, iterating between more workbooks, don't you need to insert a row after the existing last one? You can proceed in your way, the existing records going down, but I thought that it is a little more elegant to have last workbook input like last filled row... Anyhow, glad to help!

Comment: Good point! does moving existing records down consume more memory (causes excel to crash somehow)? also I don't really know in what arrangement `Dir(path & "*.xlsm")` opens the excel files, by date modified? or by name? _Maybe I should ask this in another question_ anyways thanks!

Comment: @Thamus: Only in case of big file and formula using, which need to re-reference the rows. But I was basically thinking of a king of elegance... Of course, it's up to everyone's taste... :)

Answer (score 0):

UserPicture works with file path. Try below method, it should work.

```
Set cb = Worksheets(2).Range("F3").AddComment
cb.Text Text:=""
cb.Shape.Fill.UserPicture ("FILE_PATH")
```

And if you want to copy picture from worksheet only, then you can export the pictures in tmp folder using the following code and then give the same path in UserPicture.

```
Sub SaveImages()
    Dim shpName As Variant
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim ppt As Object, ps As Variant, slide As Variant

    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")
    Set ps = ppt.presentations.Add

    Set slide = ps.slides.Add(1, 1)

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shpName = "D:\\tmp.jpg"
        shp.Copy
        With slide
            .Shapes.Paste
            .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Export shpName, 2
            .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Delete
        End With
    Next shp
    With ps
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
    ppt.Quit
    Set ppt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Q: How do you get the file path of an image copied to the clipboard?

Comment: A: Was Updating the same. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @Thamus: You must firstly save/export the picture. This can be done using a dummy chart object, able to receive the picture from clipboard (simply using Paste) and then exporting the chart as picture. Having the exported picture path, you can do what the answer suggested, using that path...

Comment: @Thamus: I have added the code to export image from excel file.